# How to fix flex android apps horizontal?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

I am developing a app running at android pad,I need fix the layout horizontal.
I know that with java,I could set a attribute in a xml file,but I couldn't find a file like this in my flex project.
So how could I fix the app horizontal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the  `<aspectRatio>` to `landscape` in your application's descriptor file.
You can find that file directly in the src folder under `yourAppName-app.xml`.

Keep in mind that the current version of Flash Builder has a bug which displays landscape marked apps as portrait in the Flash Builder emulator. If you deploy the application, the correct aspect ratio is set, though.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml -> Tab Application -> Application Nodes -> choose activity and in the field "Screen orientation" choose landscape.

Answer (score -1):

Place layouts for portret mode in /res/layouts/
Place layouts for landspace mode in /res/layout-land

Layouts xml must have same neme, for example mail.xml